# Inconsistent link targets on close/flag box?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I've noticed that the links to other sites' FAQs on the close/flag for off topic open in a new tab/window:

[[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9y4A.png)

---

However, links to the same site will open in the same tab/window:

[[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3stY.png)

[[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2nq7.png)

---

I find this handling of links rather inconsistent. Could they either all target a new tab/window, or all target the same window? I understand the difference may be due to the fact those links are to other sites, but they all result in a visit to a FAQ or similar that provide guidance on closing/moving; I feel they should have the same behaviour.

I would personally prefer them all to open in a new tab/window, so if I accidentally close it I'm back at the vote to close box where I can make my decision with the advice of the FAQ.